# Confused with exponential laws

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I was reviewing natural exponential laws when I got confused:

We have that (*) $a^mb^n=(ab)^{(m+n)}$, therefore $$a^na^n={(a^2)}^{2n}$$
And by (**) ${(a^m)}^{n}=a^{mn}$ we get
$$a^na^n={a^{4n}}$$

But from (***) $a^ma^n=a^{m+n}$ we get

$$a^na^n={a^{2n}}$$

I see as the only possible problem the equations (*),(**), and (***). Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: * is wrong.  *** is correct

Comment: How much is $2^3 \times 3^5$?  Use a calculator, and then see if your original formula applies.

Comment: If $m=n=1$ is $a^1b^1=ab=(ab)^2?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(*)$ is wrong.  $(***)$  is correct

As an indication that $(*)$ $a^mb^n=(ab)^{(m+n)}$ is wrong,
try $$2^2 \times 3^1 =12 \not= (2 \times 3)^{(2+1)}=216$$

Comment: What is true is that $a^nb^n=(ab)^n$, but that would lead to $a^na^n=(a^2)^n=a^{2n}$ as you have already found